# Java - Clicking on an image using HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

I'm doing a personal project that involves getting data out of a website, I managed to make it automatically log in and all of that, but i have reached a point where i have to click on an image

```
img src="data:image/png;base64, {{sc.PhotoLocation}}" style="width: 75px; margin-top:3px;cursor:pointer" class="ng-cloak" ng-click="sc.selectPerson(sc.person_Guid)" title="View Student Record" /
```

to progress to another menu of that page, after multiple google searches and documentations i decided on using XPath

```
HtmlImage image = page.<HtmlImage>getFirstByXPath("//img[@src=\'data:image/png;base64, sc.PhotoLocation}}\']");

page = (HtmlPage) image.click();
```

problem is, i'm getting a NullPointerException out of this, anything i did wrong? Thanks.

Rest Of The Code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://myWebsite");

HtmlInput username = page.getElementByName("Template1$MenuList1$TextBoxUsername");
username.setValueAttribute("myUsername");
HtmlInput password = page.getElementByName("Template1$MenuList1$TextBoxPassword");
password.setValueAttribute("myPassword");

HtmlSubmitInput loginButton = page.getElementByName("Template1$MenuList1$ButtonLogin");
page = loginButton.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
if (page.getElementByName("Template1$Control0$ButtonContinue") != null) {
    HtmlSubmitInput continueButton = page.getElementByName("Template1$Control0$ButtonContinue");
    page = continueButton.click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Orestesk Welcome to SO,

Your xpath is not correct.

`src` attribute of you image is dynamic. `src="data:image/png;base64, {{sc.PhotoLocation}}"`

Here `{{sc.PhotoLocation}}` would evaluate to some value. So value of `src` attribute keeps changing depending on the value of `sc.PhotoLocation`.

Use some other strategy to select your image instead of relying on src attribute.

OR try this trick.

`//img[contains(@src, 'data:image/png;base64')]`

Comment: Thanks, going to try to click a specific x/y in the page

Comment: If you have control over html, you can add an `id` field to image tag. That would be simplest and safest option.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, i'm trying to get a schedule table from a school run website

Comment: In that case, try using the trick i have added in answer. Basically it will select all `img` tags whose `src` attribute contains `data:image/png;base64`.

Comment: Can you upvote the answer if that was useful. Thanks!!